# Links opening page *over* current page

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, xhtml, svg

I have a website (here: http://kitandmarcin.us) with links to a variety of external pages. So far, so normal.

However, when one clicks on a link, the address bar doesn't change, and for some of the links, it is clearly painting over the current page (my page shows through transparent parts of the target page).

I get this behaviour in FF5, and Chrome. Investigating the structure of the document in Chrome (but not FF+firebug) shows that the embed element changes from containing the SVG to containing the target page. This behaviour was not present in earlier versions of Chrome, nor in FF3 or 4.

The one twist that my links are embedded in SVG, which is embedded in the page.

The xhtml which embeds the svg:

```
<embed type="image/svg+xml" id="svg2" data="wedding_layout.svg" src="wedding_layout.svg"/>
```

A fragment of the SVG document, which embeds the xhtml:

```
<foreignObject id="foreignObject4221-Gifts" width="225" height="175" x="689.48" y="375" class="body-box">
    <html:body class="body-body" style="text-align: center;width:100%;">
      <html:div style="text-align: center;border-style:none;width:100%;" class="body-cell"> <html:p>Gifts are not expected, but will be gratefully received</html:p><html:p>We have registered with <html:a href="http://www.williams-sonoma.com/registry/2812940/registry-list.html">Williams-Sonoma</html:a> and <html:a href="http://www.jonathanadler.com/giftregs.php?eventid=1421">Jonathan Adler</html:a></html:p>
      </html:div>
    </html:body>
</foreignObject>
```

Is there any way to stop this without using javascript? For example, can I use a target property on the `a` tags somehow?

If javascript is the only way, is there anything I should know about?

**Update**: A quick test shows that FF5 and Chrome on windows respect the `target="_top"` attribute, and load the links as expected if that is set.

**Update 2**: This also seems to work with FF5 on Mac.

Comment: This is the strangest website structure I've ever seen... I had no idea you could embed a functional webpage inside an SVG file.

Comment: Also, are you aware that your entire page scales with the window height? It is unreadable on my machine if the window isn't fullscreen...

Comment: @Hughes: That is the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"` on the embedded html anchors to navigate to the link in the current page. This eliminates the unexpected behaviour you were encountering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use target = "_blank" which will open in another browser window...

Answer (score 0):

[Remove/Delete all]. [stop all process/kill]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.